# Append Child Elements to a Child Element in the same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you append child elements to a sibling using jQuery?

html

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one">...</div>
  <div class="child">...</div>
  <div class="child">...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one">...</div>
  <div class="child">...</div>
  <div class="child">...</div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('.child').each(function(i, obj){
  if(!$(obj).hasClass('one')){
    $(obj).appendTo( .. Stuck here .. '.one');
  }
});
```

I can get the parent object but the trouble is then selecting the child with class 'one'.

Essentially I want to move all siblings so that the become children of the first child.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one">
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one">
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get each element with class `one`, then append its siblings with class `child`.

```
$('.child.one').each(function(i, obj){
  $(obj).siblings('.child').each(function(j, child){
    $(child).appendTo(obj);
  });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EaPyS/2/)**

Note: if you want the `child` elements outside the `one` element, replace `appendTo` with `after`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to append all the `child` not `one` into `child one`?

```
$('.child').not('.one').appendTo('.one');
```

**[THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/H39qE/)**

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for only I can use appendTo('.one') because there will be multiple instances of parent with child 'one'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.child').each(function(){
 if(!$(this).hasClass('one')){
  $(this).appendTo('.one');
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dAXJ2/20/)**